# Bases and transversals

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free finitely generated group, $L \leq H \leq F$ subgroups of finite index.

1. Given bases $B$ of $F$ and $C$ of $H$, must there be a Schreier transversal $T$ for $H$ in $F$ such that the basis constructed from $T$ and $B$ is $C$ (using the standart basis construction procedure, as in the proof of the Nielsen-Schreier theorem)?
2. Given a basis $C$ of $H$, must there be a Schreier transversal $T$ for $H$ in $F$ and a basis $B$ of $F$ such that the basis constructed from $T$ and $B$ is $C$?
3. If a basis $B$ for $H$ is constructed from a basis $A$ for $F$ and some transversal, and a basis $C$ for $L$ is constructed from the basis $B$ for $H$ and some transversal, must there be a transversal giving rise to $C$ from $A$?

Comment: It's easy to find counterexamples to 1 with $F$ of rank $2$ and $|F:H|=2$. There are only four Schreier transversals to consider.

Comment: I mainly suspect that the transitivity condition in 3 is true...